# LWUIT J2ME Using VirtualKeyboard

Tags: java-me, lwuit, virtual-keyboard

Is it possible to use virtual keyboard without assign it to `TextField`/`TextArea` ?

In doc is said the VK must be linked to some `Component` ( `bindVirtualKeyboard()` ).

I have a `Label` and some `Button`. After clicking on `Button` I woud like to show virtual keybord for numbers.

After typing is finished I would like to change text in my `Label` component.

Of course even I can able to show keyboard I can't get value from keyboard because it is not assigned to any `TextField`.

Is it possible to do what I described ? If do can you explain how to do it or maybe there's some example ?

Best regards,

Mel

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the `VirtualKeyboard` code, it is technically just a Dialog which you can subclass and show/used as you see fit. What you want won't work well via the standard show API because that's too generic (for native VKB support) but should work with the actual LWUIT `VirtualKeyboard` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

ı am wondering about why you need data that comes from keyboard ,just changing label text?if that why dont u use textbox ?

I've read too much about virtual keyboard and understood that I cant get the input from keyboard(it is virtual or not) if there is no textbox clicked at that moment